# sum of the items of a nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do some calculations inside ng-repeat where i want to get the total price out from each nested ng-repeat from the list.

```
<div class="Container" ng-repeat="items in list">

  <div class="top">i am in the top {{items.date}}</div>

    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <a>{{item.count}}</a>
      <a ng-init="setTotals(total = (item.count * item.price))">{{item.price}}</a>   
    </div>

  <div class=bottom">total price: {{totalPrice}}</div>

</div>
```

this is the angular scope i try to get:

```
    $scope.setTotals = function (total) {
        $scope.totalPrice = total * total;
    }
```

but this just doubles the output of a single item, how would i be able to get the total amount of all the items in the nested ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list of items is like:

```
$scope.list = [
    {date: '2017-12-14', items: [
        {count: 3, price: 9},
        {count: 1, price: 20}
    ]},
    {date: '2017-12-15', items: [
        {count: 2, price: 10},
        {count: 5, price: 20}
    ]}
];
```

And that you want to calculate sum of prices per day with function:

```
$scope.calculateTotal = function (dayItems) {
    let total = 0;
        for (item of dayItems.items) {
            total += (item.count * item.price);
        };
    return total;
}
```

The html becomes like:

```
<div class="Container" ng-repeat="items in list">

  <div class="top">i am in the top {{items.date}}</div>

    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items.items">
      <a>{{item.count}}</a>
      <a>{{item.price}}</a>   
    </div>

  <div class=bottom">total price: {{calculateTotal(items)}}</div>

</div>
```

See [working demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YGRdWjQayrZeEdgAJvyZ?p=preview). Of course you can modify code to fit your needs, it is only a sample implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Add function to controller:

```
$scope.getTotalPrice = function(items)
{
    return items.reduce(function(sum, item)
    {
        return (sum + (item.count * item.price));
    }, 0);
};
```

call it in html:

```
<div class="Container" ng-repeat="items in list">

  <div class="top">i am in the top {{items.date}}</div>

    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <a>{{item.count}}</a>
      <a>{{item.price}}</a>   
    </div>

  <div class=bottom">total price: {{ getTotalPrice(items) }}</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is to do the calculation logic in your controller and just display its result in your view:

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.totalPrice = $scope.items..reduce((sum, item) => {
     return (sum + item.count * item.price);
}, 0);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container" ng-repeat="items in list">

  <div class="top">i am in the top {{items.date}}</div>

  <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a>{{item.count}}</a>
    <a>{{item.price}}</a>
  </div>

  <div class=bottom ">total price: {{totalPrice}}</div>

</div>
```